# How to adjust the bitrate Kazam?

Tags: screencast, kazam

How to configure Kazam, so that the recording quality was high bitrate? I tried to record a screencast, but the quality in general ((. I need the highest bitrate. Tnx!

Comment: I could be old and slow but under Xenial I could not find the Preferences dialogue to make the required changes. There is a conf file: `$HOME/.config/kazam/kazam.conf` but not much of use there :(